# N'-band channelizer (filter bank) via Sliding FFT

Tags: matlab, fft, filters, discrete-signals, signal-analysis

I'm trying to figure out how to perform N'-band channelizer for SSCA (strip spectral correlation analyzer) via sliding FFT. I understand that I have to take $N$ points of signal in time domain $x(t)$, apply a windowing function and take another $N$ points by shifting the window by $L$ ($L=1$ in my case). Then I apply Fourier transform to those points. But how many of those windowed vectors do I need? I tried to follow code in *commP25ssca.m* but I can't understand steps between the final result (and then can't set proper input values to the mentioned function).

- SSCA blog:
  https://cyclostationary.blog/2016/03/22/csp-estimators-the-strip-spectral-correlation-analyzer/
- Documentation for matlab function:
  https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/ADA311555.pdf
- My code for simple sliding fft via following this paper:
  [https://www.comm.utoronto.ca/~dimitris/ece431/slidingdft.pdf](https://www.comm.utoronto.ca/%7Edimitris/ece431/slidingdft.pdf)

```
clc
clear all
close all
ef = 0.1;
ef_vz = 1;
Td = 1000;
time = 0:1/ef_vz:Td;
freq = 0:1/Td:ef_vz;
sig = 1*exp(1j*2*pi*ef.*time);
spek = abs(fft(sig));
N = 512;
num_blocks = floor((length(sig)-N) / 1);
x = sig;
counter = 0;
for i = 1:length(x)
    
    k = [i:i+N-1];
    window = x(k);
    if i == 1
        Xk(i,:) = fft(x(k));
    else
        Xk(i,:) = (Xk(i-1,:)-x(i)+x(i+N-1)).*exp((1j*2*pi*(k-1))/N);
    end
    counter = counter + 1;
    if counter == 1
        break
    else
        continue
    end
   
end
p = linspace(0,ef_vz,N);
figure(1)
plot(p,abs(Xk))
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess I've solve this problem by using part of steps described in blog about FAM estimator (steps 1.-3.).
https://cyclostationary.blog/2018/06/01/csp-estimators-the-fft-accumulation-method/

Also De Costa paper which is related with commP25ssca.m function helped me a lot. I think to obtain SSCA I need implement these two figures:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVwHn.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9PzU.jpg

Here is code if somebody will need it:

```
Np = 64;
N = 32768;  

input = xx(1:N);

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%      N'point data to sublock

xbuff = [input, zeros(1,Np)];
subblock = zeros(Np,N);
for i = 1:Np
    subblock(i,:) = xbuff(i:i+N-1);
end

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%      Apply window function and FFT

a = hamming(Np);
X = zeros(Np,N);
for j = 1:N
    X(:,j) = fft(a.*subblock(:,j));
end

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%      Phase shifting

E = zeros(Np,N);

for idxl = -Np/2:Np/2-1    % length of l is Np
    for k = 0:N-1          % length of k is P
        E(idxl+Np/2+1,k+1) = exp(-1j*2*pi*k*idxl/Np);
    end
end

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

XT = X.*E;

ReferBin = ones(Np,1)*input;
Xtx = XT.*conj(ReferBin);

SX = zeros(Np,N);
for i = 1:Np
    SX(i,:) = fft(Xtx(i,:));
end

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```